# how to view the error stack trace in android?

Tags: android, stack-trace

Can someone tell me clearly from where i can view the android error stack trace? i tried searching , but never found a clear-cut answer

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack traces are exposed via LogCat, either in an IDE window, or via adb logcat on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Print your stack trace and check the message in the Logcat (using DDMS) tool.

For more info about debugging, see [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse you have the logcat view.

If you can't see it go to : Windows > Show View > Others and in the box look for the Android folder you'll see the LogCat view.